# Draggable video scrubbing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5-video

I have a MP4 video of a product which shows a 360 of the product (so it looks like it's spinning) - I have it autoplaying on the page and looks great.

I want the user to be able to click and drag on the video to basically rewind or fastforward the video, so they can kind of scroll back and forth and spin the product around as they wish.

We have used the js-cloudimage-360-view library and used images, but because we wanted this as smooth as possible each colour had 360 images and loading times weren't great, we have MP4s which are small in size and load fast but it's just the srubbing I can't get right.

I'd had a look at this https://codepen.io/webandapp/pen/xEjjOJ too but it's supper jumpy, essentially we want if the user drags to the right it fast forwards as they drag, when they stop it should play from that point (and rewinds if dragging to the left) - this should be as smooth as possible.

The video is just a HTML video element like so:

```
<video id="three-sixty-video" preload="auto" controls loop playsinline autoplay muted>
   <source src="/video/video-1.mp4" type="video/mp4;">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrubbing on a streamed video is limited by the speed at which the video can be downloaded, decoded and displayed.

For a large video on most devices and connections it is not practical/possible to do all this as quickly as a user can scroll along the video timeline.

This is why video containers (mp4 etc) often include a track of thumbnail images which are displayed when the user scrubs along the line.

In other words, it is not actually the video you see in the small image in the timeline, but the appropriate thumbnail for that time in the video.

When the user stop scrubbing, the player then requests that section of the video, decodes and displays it. This is (generally) not immediate.

If your video is small enough and is downloaded completely then you may find you can scrub as quickly as you want, but even then it may be device/client dependent - a quick local test with a number of videos seem to suggest it should scrub ok when available locally:

- Using a relatively small 30MB, 50 second local mp4 video, available locally on he computer hard drive (a MAC), scrubbing is relatively smooth using the Quicktime client player.
- The same video on the same device being viewed by the Safari browser rather than directly by the QuickTime client appears to be similar, although it is hard to be sure. The playback may well use very similar paths under the skin.
- Using a much larger 2G, 4K, 2 minute 30 second video, also locally on the hard drive, scrubbing is again relatively smooth both in Safari and QuickTime.

As a side note, if you do decide the solution is to have the video fully downloaded before you play, that is also an interesting challenge. Most effort is usually focused on the opposite, allowing a video to start playing before it fully downloads. You may find that, providing the video is not too big, having the header info at the end (the MooV atom for mp4) will force the browser to download it fully. This is the opposite of the mp4 faststart you will see discussed some places. I'm not sure how reliable this will be as I think some browser may be clever enough to 'search' in the video by making different requests for bytes at the start and end to find the metadata.

Comment: I think Asker is looking for something like this [video timeline scrubber](https://jordicenzano.github.io/frame-accurate-scrubbing/ui/player/example_player.html?m=../../media/transcoded/scrubbingTestV3/854x480/main_manifest.json). Your point about thumbnails is close to their solution, which is using JPEGs. They have [an article](https://jordicenzano.github.io/frame-accurate-scrubbing/) about their production process, maybe the Asker might learn an idea or two from it...